# Out of Memory from capuring screenshots

Tags: c#, winforms, screenshot

Hello there I have a problem. I have a setup to capture Screenshots of my WebBrowser control:

```
public static class Utilities
{
    public const int SRCCOPY = 13369376;

    public static Image CaptureScreen()
    {
        return CaptureWindow(User32.GetDesktopWindow());
    }

    public static Image CaptureWindow(IntPtr handle)
    {

        IntPtr hdcSrc = User32.GetWindowDC(handle);

        User32.RECT windowRect = new User32.RECT();
        User32.GetWindowRect(handle, ref windowRect);

        int width = windowRect.right - windowRect.left;
        int height = windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top;

        IntPtr hdcDest = Gdi32.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSrc);
        IntPtr hBitmap = Gdi32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSrc, width, height);

        IntPtr hOld = Gdi32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hBitmap);
        Gdi32.BitBlt(hdcDest, 0, 0, width, height, hdcSrc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        Gdi32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hOld);
        Gdi32.DeleteDC(hdcDest);
        User32.ReleaseDC(handle, hdcSrc);

        Image image = Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);
        Gdi32.DeleteObject(hBitmap);

        return image;
    }
}

public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static Image DrawToImage(this Control control)
    {
        return Utilities.CaptureWindow(control.Handle);
    }
}

public class Gdi32
{
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hObject, int nXDest, int nYDest, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hObjectSource, int nXSrc, int nYSrc, int dwRop);
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleBitmap(IntPtr hDC, int nWidth, int nHeight);
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hDC);
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern bool DeleteDC(IntPtr hDC);
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hDC, IntPtr hObject);
}

public static class User32
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int left;
        public int top;
        public int right;
        public int bottom;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT rect);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);
}
```

And I have a timer on 100ms to show the WebBrowser at 10fps in a picturebox:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox2.Image = ControlExtensions.DrawToImage(webBrowser1);
    }
```

But from this goes my memory 100mb up per secound.

Did I miss something that clears the memory?

//EDIT
@N4TKD now i got it:

```
        if (pictureBox2.Image != null)
            pictureBox2.Image.Dispose();
        pictureBox2.Image = ControlExtensions.DrawToImage(webBrowser1);
```

thank you

Comment: are you cleaning the picture box before you are adding a new picture? I think you are just stacking images.

Comment: @N4TKD i used the following before:  pictureBox1.Image = null;
            pictureBox1.Image = ControlExtensions.DrawToImage(webBrowser1);

Comment: @code4fun4ever if you solved your problem please either answer your own question as a answer and mark it accepted in two days or delete the question. If you don't it will keep appearing on the front page as a question with no accepted answer every few months.

Comment: @Scott i cant I dont have enough repulation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The garbage collector will clean up after you, but it can't get the job done properly for the Image class.  Which is a very small managed wrapper class around a big pile of *unmanaged* memory that stores the pixel data of an image.  You will run out of memory before you've created enough Image objects to trigger a GC.

Explicitly disposing the old images is *required*.

Comment: So one wonders why the framework's Image class doesn't use `GC.AddMemoryPressure`, which is the function designed to account for the unmanaged memory usage when deciding whether to GC.

Comment: @BenVoigt Because it may or may not be memory that he is actually running out of. `Image` uses GDI under the hood and GDI is notorious for throwing `OutOfMemoryExecption`s when really what has happened is you have run out of [GDI handles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which windows does not provide relatively many of (the default was 10,000 on my machine)

Comment: @Scott: Depends on the frame dimensions of course. In general, you are right, and Hans's explanation falls somewhere between incomplete and totally misleading.

Comment: No, it is actual memory he's running out of here.  Screenshots are big enough.  The trouble with AddMemoryPressure is that GDI+ doesn't give any way to discover how much VM is being consumed, it is a codec implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

My GDI is a bit rusty on order of operations... but have you tried moving `Gdi.DeleteDC(hdcDest)` after `Gdi32.DeleteObject(hBitmap)`?

It would seem like `DeleteDC` should be the last thing you do after cleaning up all associated objects with that DC.

Here is how I would think to reorder it:

```
    IntPtr hOld = Gdi32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hBitmap);
    Gdi32.BitBlt(hdcDest, 0, 0, width, height, hdcSrc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    Image image = Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);

    Gdi32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hOld);
    Gdi32.DeleteObject(hBitmap);

    Gdi32.DeleteDC(hdcDest);
    User32.ReleaseDC(handle, hdcSrc);
```

Comment: I just forgot to Dispose the image in the imagebox